# Periodic desktop save

Tags: desktop

How can I have emacs save my desktop periodically, so it will persist even if I do not exit with `C-c C-x` in `desktop-save-mode` or save manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, one would use a
[timer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html)
to repeat a task at given time intervals.  However, the manual
node on [Saving Emacs
Sessions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions)
states that:

> When `desktop-save-mode` is active and the desktop file exists,
>   Emacs auto-saves it every `desktop-auto-save-timeout` seconds,
>   if that is non-`nil` and non-zero.

I found this information by looking in the elisp manual on
[Desktop Save
Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Desktop-Save-Mode.html)
and following the link to the manual node on [Saving Emacs
Sessions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions).